# How to dynamically inject WebDriver path and WebDrivers at runtime

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I am trying to learn selenium for automated testing. ( and this is the first time i am using Eclipse IDE) Every examples i am following i see something along the line below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    WebDriver driver;
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\mylibs\chromedriver.exe");
    driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.navigate().to("myurl");      
}
```

Questions

1> If i am working in team environment the above code will not work if other team member does not have the same path for ChromeDriver. How do i inject path?

2> Code needs to target multiple browsers like Chrome, IE, Edge, etc. That means i cannot newup the specific WebDriver ( like the ChromeDriver in my example above) How do i inject Specific WebDrivers at run time?

3>Also why not use `RemoteWebDriver` as type instead of `WebDriver`? Looks like every specific WebDriver is derived from `RemoteWebDriver` and `RemoteWebDriver` has more methods to work with?

Now for the first 2 questions, one solution is make use of args, something like below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
        RemoteWebDriver driver;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", args[0]+chromedriver.exe");

        if(args[1] == "chrome")
        {
            driver=new ChromeDriver();
        }

        if(args[1] == "edge")
        {
            driver= new EdgeDriver();
        }

        if(args[1] == "ie")
        {
            driver= new IEDriver();
        }       

        driver.navigate().to("myurl");      
    }
```

Is there any better way to do it?

**Update 1**

Based on answers i received i think i am not clear with my Question 2.
When testers are done with writing all the tests, i am assuming during the regression test we don't run these tests from Eclipse. I am guessing some CI tool ,for example `jenkins`, will have to execute these tests automatically for all supported browsers we need to test. That means Jenkins needs to know where the web drivers are located on the build server. That path could be different from Tester's local path on his local machine that he/she used during development. Also Jenkins needs to inject different web driver for each browser specific test. So we cannot hard code the specific web driver in the code, it needs to be supplied at the start of the tests. (something like dependency injection)

Answer (score 0):

***(Q: 1)***

For starters, in java the backslash character '\' is an escape character, so to specify a windows path, each backslash mush contain 2 to insert 1 into a string.

So your path should look like: "C:\\Windows\\Drivers\\etc..."

When you say "Inject" the path, you "Inject" it with System.setProperty(a, b)

You will need to know the path values before hand to "Inject" anything into the system properties.

***One solution***, which involves communicating, is to tell them to install their driver files on the root of their drives, so it can be accessed with your hard-coded path.

You can also, simply enough, include the required files inside of the jar file itself.

***Another, coded solution***, would be to search known, or common directories where the files may be stored. This can be done with recursion in the following code

```
/** @param searchDirectory - this can be whole system searched,
  * by starting at "C:\\".
  * Otherwise, give it more defined paths of common directories */
public String getPath(String searchDirectory, String fileName) {
    File folder = new File(searchDirectory);
    File[] files = folder.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            return getPath(file.getPath(), fileName);
        } else if (file.getName().equals(fileName)) {
            return file.getPath();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

***(Q: 2)***

If you want to actually dynamically inject code into a running jar file, which is not at all necessary here, you're going to set yourself on a whole new research expedition to make yourself a little hacker.

However,

When specifying arguments into the main method, *(looking at your example of how you're choosing to pass the arguments)*, you'll need to specify the property specific to which web driver is specified in the argument.

This can easily be done like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver." + args[1] + ".driver", args[0] + args[1] + "driver.exe");
    switch (args[1]) {
    case "chrome":
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        break;
    case "edge":
        driver = new EdgeDriver();
        break;
    case "ie":
        driver = new IEDriver();
        break;
    }        
}
```

***(Q: 3)***

Whether or not you want to use "RemoteWebDriver" is up to you, check the API Docs for selenium and make sure it is compatible with what you are attempting to preform.

Comment: Hi, I tried your Q:2 fix on dynamically alternating between IE and Chrome at my side. 

I did a successful test run on IE and called the main method again to parse in the args chrome (without stopping the application), to start the chrome test run.

However, I am getting the error "The process cannot access the file 'C:\.......\chromedriver.exe' because it is being used by another process"...

Vice versa as I do a successful test run on chrome followed by IE.... how do i overcome it?

Comment: Probably copy and paste that file into a new directory or with a different name and you should be good, just change the code accordingly to match the new name of the file

Answer (score 0):

For Ques 1, you can keep the driver in the project folder itself. This way, all the team members will have the same folder location for the driver.

For Ques 2, multiple environments and browsers can be managed by using property files. Execution on remote machines during regression can be set using using CI tools